# Laplace transform of $( \sin t)/t$

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform

I have a question about this example from *Fundamentals of Differential Equations* by Nagle:
[image]
Why can we interchange the infinite sum and the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}$? Specifically, why is it true that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k}dt=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}t^{2k}dt$$
I was thinking we must look at the infinite series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}e^{-st}t^{2k}$$
(with fixed $s>0$ and as a function of $t$). I was thinking either to a) show the partial sums of the above converge uniformly to swap the integral and infinite sum, but I think uniform convergence is false because the maximal value of each term of the sum occurs at $t=2k$, and we have a $(2k)^{2k}$ term that overpowers everything else.
or b) try to use Dominated convergence, but I need an integrable function that is an upper bound of each partial sum, which I'm also having trouble finding.
Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the $(2k)^{2k}$ term also overpower the $1/(2k+1)!$ factor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The interchange of sum and integral is permissible if $\sum \int |\frac {e^{-st}t^{2k}} {(2k+1)!}|\, dt <\infty $ [This is by Fubini's Theorem]. For $t <1$, $\sum \frac {e^{-st}t^{2k}} {(2k+1)!} \leq \sum \frac {e^{-st}} {(2k+1)!} < e^{1-st}$. For $t >1$, $\sum \frac {e^{-st}t^{2k}} {(2k+1)!} \leq \frac 1 t \sum \frac {t^{2k+1}e^{-st}} {(2k+1)!} < e^{-(s-1)t}$. Hence $e^{-(s-1)t}+e^{1-st}$ is an upper bound for the sum for all $t$. Of course $\int_0^{\infty } (e^{-(s-1)t}+e^{1-st}) <\infty $  for $s >1$.

Comment: $\sum \int f_n (x) dx= \int \sum f_n(x) dx$ if $\sum \int |f_n (x)| dx <\infty $. This is by Fubini's Theorem. Can someone explain the down vote please.

Comment: @Jason My answer justifies interchange of integral and sum. DCT is not the only way for this. If you have questions about my proof feel free to ask for more details.